# Relationship between UPF/SPF and reduction in UV damage

Tags: risks, sun-exposure, uv-rays, spf-sun-protection-factor, sunscreen-sunblock

I'm trying to untangle the relationship between the UPF/SPF rating of clothing or sunscreen and its effectiveness at reducing health risks from exposure to sunlight.

The first complication is that a UPF/SPF rating represents the denominator of the fraction of UV radiation that passes through the protective barrier.  This means that there are diminishing returns on higher UPF/SPF ratings.  For example, a mere UPF 5 blocks 80% of UV radiation.  Doubling the UPF rating blocks half of the *remaining* radiation, which is only 10% of the original amount.  Doubling it again only blocks another 5%.  Et cetera.

The second complication is that the health effect of UV radiation may be non-linear.  In other words, an 80% reduction in exposure may result in more or less than an 80% reduction in risk.

Ideally, I'm looking for an answer that takes these factors into account, expressing health risk as a function of UPF/SPF while holding exposure time constant.